# Сохранение и редактирование файла в res/raw на андроид

Tags: android, java

Всем добрый день!
При разработке приложения возник вопрос.
Мне необходимо парсить файл посредством JSON. Файл находится в папке res/raw, но мне необходимо этот файл постоянно обновлять из инета. Подскажите как можно его содержимое заменить содержимым файла который находится по определенной ссылке. Может есть подобные примеры? 
Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так, накидал, но не проверял. Не претендует на самую лучшую реализацию, но для начала пойдет

```
/**
 * Копирует файл из ресурсов
 */
public static void copyFileFromRaw(Context mContext,Sting FILE_NAME)
{

    getCurrentVersionCode();
    File file1 = new File(FILE_PATH);
    try
    {
        //проверяем существует ли такой файл, если нет, то выпадет ошибка и нужно копровать, если нет, то ничего делать не будем
        mContext.openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        try
        {
             Input Stream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);

            //Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE - дает доступ другим приложениям к этому файлу, если оне не нужен то можно
            //поставить Context.Context.MODE_PRIVATE,
            FileOutputStream fout = mContext.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            copyFromTo(inputStream, fout);
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//выполняет запрос для текстового файла
public static String executeHttpGet(String uri) throws Exception
{

    String result = "";
    try
    {

        URL url = new URL(uri);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
           result +=str;
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

//получет по ссылке новое содержимое файла, и перезаписывает
public void rewriteFileFromUrl(String url)
{
    Sring file_souce = executeHttpGet(url);
    rewriteUpdateFile(file_souce,FILE_NAME);
}

/**
 * Переписывает файл
 * тут, когда вы получите текст по ссылке, то просто посылаем в этот метод
 * @param str - текст файла 
 */
private void rewriteUpdateFile(String str, Sting FILE_NAME)
{

    try
    {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        FileOutputStream fout = mContext.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        copyFromTo(is, fout);
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * Копирует из одного потока в другой информацию
 * @param fin поток копируемого файла
 * @param fout поток файла в который будет все записано
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void copyFromTo(InputStream fin, OutputStream fout) throws IOException
{
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int noOfBytes = 0;

    while ((noOfBytes = fin.read(b)) != -1)
    {
        fout.write(b, 0, noOfBytes);
    }

    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: А куда идет запись файла. Имею в виду по какому адресу мне открывать файл для работы JSON. Огромное спасибо за помощь! Буду пробовать!

Comment: в данном примере запись идет в директорию context.getFilesDir()

Answer (score 2):

Распакуй дефолтный файл из raw на карту памяти, и уже с ним работай

Comment: А напрямую файл в папке raw нельзя работать?

Comment: имел ввиду комментировать!

Comment: из ресурсов можно только читать, изменять их нельзя, перенеси файл в доступное для приложение место и там работай с ний

Comment: читать из ресурсов, а следовательно легко распаковать на карту.
По сути ресурсы сделаны или для статичных данных, или для первоначальных, пока новые не подгружены из интернета

Comment: Я открываю json файл следующим образом.
Input Stream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
String jsontext = new String(buffer);
final JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);

Как его открыть если он на сд карте? И где в таком случае его безопаснее хранить?

Comment: Хранить? Например в дериктории кеша вашего приложения.
Открыть? Ну вот вам самый простой пример
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902689/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-sd-card-in-android

Comment: @vanyamelikov в директории приложения. context.getFilesDir() - возвратит нужный вам путь :)

Comment: @Andreich скорее правильнее будет context.getCacheDir()

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать! А может есть пример замены содержимого файла на содержимое пос ссылке!

Comment: @AndroidDev это уже смотря для чего

Comment: @vanyamelikov вот вам пример, того что тут описывали :)
директории конечно же можно менять, в зависимости от ваших потребностей